# How to calculate number of days between dates taking in account day saving shift?

Tags: java, date, calendar, dst

I have found advice like:

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar1.set(2007, 01, 10);
calendar2.set(2007, 07, 01);
long milliseconds1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
long milliseconds2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();
long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

But when changing time from winter to summer there is a 1 hour difference. Is there a common method to calculate this? Thanks.

Comment: Also concern about leap second, leap year, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider to use joda-time library, which provides much more useful date time interface. For example, your question is solved jsut like this: `Days.daysBetween(startInstant, endInstant).getDays()`

As for using standart Calendar -- I can't consider better alternative then using Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) -- this will gives you ability to get difference in days during one calendar year. To spread this method to several years I can suggest only iterate though all intermediate years between start and end moments, summing Calendar.getActualMaximum(DAY_OF_YEAR). Not very convenient way, but...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the timezone of each Calendar.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28java.util.TimeZone%29

BTW: Joda Time may be a nicer solution.

Java doesn't support leap seconds. As such its treats UTC as being the same as GMT.